# How to make a box acts like a box collider

Tags: javascript, c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game project using Unity 5 and I have created some buildings with Building Generator v0.7 plugin in 3Ds Max and then I inserted them into Unity but the problem comes from where I wanted to add Box Collider. Basically my computer couldn't handle the process because it does not a powerful system so I decided to add Box Collider using a box (3d object)! So here's an image of my building:

[image: print screen 1]

And here's the box that I wrapped around the building as Collider:

[image: print screen 2]

So my question is how to make this box acts like a collider so the box would'nt be visible but it does what it's supposed to do...

I really appreciate if you know how to solve this problem ,thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you tried to add a `BoxCollider` to the building, not a `PolygonCollider`? A BoxCollider should not stress out your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is how to make this box acts like a collider so the box
>   would'nt be visible but it does what it's supposed to do.

Simply disable `Mesh Renderer` on the cube. The collider will still be functional if `Mesh Renderer` is disabled. You can always re-enable it, use its visual to resize your Collider, then disable it again. If you think you will never need to see that cube again, then remove the `Mesh Renderer` entirely.

[image]